# How to skip over empty labels in UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

My `cell.textLabel.text` sometimes returns an empty string. Is there a way I can skip this cell and put my next text label right after my last non empty `cell.textLabel.text`? So there should no empty labels.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }
    ResultModel *resultModel = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = resultModel.resultString;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**cell.textLabel** takes the whole content view's **size.width** so you calculate the length of the string and manipulate **next label** accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
if([resultModel.resultString isEqualToString:@""])
{
    // Display the label
cell.textLabel.text = resultModel.resultString;
}
else
{
    //result  string is Null do nothing here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get instances which have value in "resultString" property?

```
NSArray *dataWithResultString = [call the custom method to get instances with no empty value];
ResultModel *resultModel = [dataWithResultString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

This you should handle in the datasource array itself...

Populate a new array with values having the resultModel.resultString  and use this array as the datasource for tables

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly you want the cell to be displayed only if there is some non empty string in resultModel.resultString, right?

For that you better handle the datasource array itself. If that's hard, you can do this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
ResultModel *resultModel = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([resultModel.resultString isEqualToString:@""])
 return 0.0;
else
 return 50;//or whatever
}
```

But its better handling the datasource itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right, the resulted array might return an empty string and if so, you don't want to show those rows right?

Ideally, you should've add another parameter to your query to **exclude** the empty `resultString`. However, if you want a *hacky* way, declare `(int)padRows` and set it to `0` in viewDidLoad;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
ResultModel *resultModel = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

while([resultModel.resultString isEqualToString:@""]) {
  _padRows += 1;
  resultModel = [self.array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row+_padRows)];
}

cell.textLabel.text = resultModel.resultString;

return cell;
}
```

*Code not tested.*